# How do Advatins classify Vaikuntha and other lokas according to their philosophy?

Tags: vedanta, advaita, brahman, lokas, maya

Do advaitins believe in Vaikuntha and other lokas and see them as eternal?

Comment: Vaikuntha means where there is no "kunthaa". That is the nature of the Self. So a loka with devas roaming around are definitely not accepted by Advaitins as Absolute.

Comment: Does that also means Gods like Vishnu and Shiva are not real according to Advaita?

Comment: yes, not real.So long as the sense of "I" is there, there is the sense of "you" also. Advaita realization is beyond the sense of dual.

Comment: @Rishx None of the attributes of Saguna brahman, like creatorship, all-pervasiveness etc. are real according to advaita. Nirguna brahman(NB) is the only reality. Essence of gods like Vishnu/Shiva is real. This essence is NB. Form and other attributes of gods is unreal.

Comment: @Rishx Yes, Advaitins accept Vaikuntha as eternal but not ultimate. Adi Shankara himself accepted krama mukti.

Comment: They think all the lokas including world of eternal liberation Vaikuntha and gods Vishnu, Shiva, etc, are all maya or illusion that should be removed. They believe when we get rid of that maya we are established in reality, the only reality which is Brahman.

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury Agreed.Though most Advatins now promotes Nirguna upasana ..claiming even Vaikuntha being maya.

Comment: @brahmajijnasa If these lokas are maya ..then why perform saguna worship at all? Adi Sanka emphasised on meditation and atma vichara but still composed stotras in praise of various deities.

Comment: @Rishx Well today's Advaitins are mostly pseudo-Advaitins. Real Advaitins are very rare now.

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury true

Comment: *If these lokas are maya ..then why perform saguna worship at all?* <-- Good question. Although saguna worship they consider to be in the realm of maya, which should be get rid of, still they think it can be beneficial to the practitioner. It can help one get rid of sins, elevate your consciousness to the level of sattva (purity), thus it helps one to elevate oneself above mundane and worldliness, above sensuality, which helps in the spiritual life. But yes, they believe all that is still in the realm of maya and cannot make you self realised in Brahman. It is only when you get rid of all ...

Comment: ... duality and sense of individuality, and when you establish yourself in qualityless nirguna Brahman, you will become self realised, they believe. So even saguna worship, they think, is maya, and ultimately should be get rid of.

Answer (score 2):

Adi Shankara himself states in his one of the strongest Prakarana Grantha **Sarva Vedanta Siddhanta Sara sangraha** that only people filled with delusion and ignorant mindset think that Prāpanchika (worldly/created/subjected to creation) lokḥās like **Vaikuntha** as eternal.

> सर्वस्यानित्यत्वे सावयवत्वेन सर्वतः सिद्धे ।
> वैकुण्ठादिषु नित्यत्वमतिर्भ्रम एव मूढबुद्धीनाम् ॥
>
> When it is established that everything made of parts is ephemeral, those of lowly intellect are deluded thinking that vaikuṇṭha, etc. are eternal.

-- **Sarva Vedanta Siddhanta Sara sangraha**

Shankara also says Vishnu is a samashti aupādhika devata who has a material body.

> एष देवो विष्णुरनन्तः प्रथमशरीरी त्रैलोक्यदेहोपाधिः सर्वेषां भूतानामन्तरात्मा । स हि सर्वभूतेषु द्रष्टा श्रोता मन्ता विज्ञाता सर्वकरणात्मा ॥
>
> This god Vishnu or Ananta, is the first embodied existence with material form, one with the three worlds as his upādhi and is the self of all beings (pancha bhūta-s). He is the seer, hearer, etc. in all beings.

**-- Mundaka Upanishad bhashya**

Swami Vidyaranya in his Panchadashi says that Vishnu is the highest material body.

> विष्ण्वाद्युत्तमदेहेषु प्रविष्टो देवताभवत् । मर्त्याद्यधमदेहेषु स्थितो भजति मर्त्यताम् ॥ २ ॥
>
> Entering the superior bodies like that of Vishnu, He became the deities; and remaining in the inferior bodies like that of men He experiences attributes of a human, like death.

Adi Shankaracharya says in his Taittiriya Upanishad bhashya that:-

> प्रजापतिः विराट् त्रैलोक्यशरीरो ब्रह्मा समष्टिव्यष्टिरूपः संसारमण्डलव्यापी ।

Beings like Prajapati (Brahma)

Few notable points:-

1. Narayanashrama (12 CE), an Advaita Vedantin who was co-disciple of Swami Vidyaranya's guru Shankarananda has written Dipikas on 4-5 Vedāntic Shaiva Upanishads from Atharvaveda namely Katharudra upanishad, Atharvarshika Upanishad, Atharvarshira Upanishad etc: which says Lord Vishnu and his existence (abode/Vaikuntha) is non-eternal (just like how Shankara maintained his stance in SVSSS) and is subjected to destruction.
2. Supporting the above point, Sayanacharya in his Purusha sukta bhashya says that positions of Samashti Jivas like Prajapati/Hiranyagarbha (Brahma) and Virat (Vishnu) can be obtained by different sadhanas.

Hence, Advaita Vedantins consider Abodes/lokhas of Brahma and Vishnu (Vaikuntha) as non-eternal samashti planets which are subjected to destruction.